# separate a string using php

Tags: php, string, variables, explode

I have a sting similar to this

```
$_POST["ids"]='ABC,DEF,GHI'
```

I want to seperate each of three variables and then run the separated results through a while loop.

```
foreach( explode( ',', $_POST["ids"]) as $Client_ID)
{
  $sql_qry="select *
            from   ca_client_statement
            where  client_id='".$Client_ID."' and trading_period_month like '".$TP_Month."'";
  $sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
  $bytes = $row['pdf_statement'];
  header("Content-type: application/pdf");
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$Client_ID.'statement'.$TP_format.'.pdf"');
  print $bytes;
}
```

This will only generate a statement for ABC. not three

Many thanks

Comment: Why don’t you try it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but I would recommend you use a `foreach` loop instead of a `while` loop after you call `explode()`, like so:

```
foreach( explode( ',', $string) as $value)
    echo $value . ' ';
```

This would print `ABC DEF GHI`.

To apply it to your sample code, you cannot call `header()` after you output something unless you have output buffering enabled.

Try this:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$Client_ID.'statement'.$TP_format.'.pdf"');
foreach( explode( ',', $_POST["ids"]) as $Client_ID)
{
  $sql_qry="select *
            from   ca_client_statement
            where  client_id='".$Client_ID."' and trading_period_month like '".$TP_Month."'";
  $sql_err_no=sql_select($sql_qry,$sql_res,$sql_row_count,$sql_err,$sql_uerr);

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res);
  $bytes = $row['pdf_statement'];
  print $bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, if I echo the statement this works perfectly. However when I try and run a mysql query and generate a pdf I only get the first result. I have updated my script above

Comment: Could not get it to work. but thanks anyway. For a single client the original code works perfectly. the header needs to be within the loop as the filename is dynamic :/

Comment: I believe you'll end up overwriting `headers()` if you keep your original approach.